# Prometheus alert testing

Tags: prometheus

i want to ask you guys what do you think about testing some prometheus alert on test environment knowing that the amount of data metrics on it won't be the same as the load on prod environment?
because in this case an alert with a threshold adapted for prod may not work that well on test environment. For example it might be ok not to receive a request for 10 min if we are on test env but this will be considered as a problem on prod.

is it relevant to do tests in this case ? is there a best practice ?

Comment: I lower down the threadhold and make the alert to trigger or manually create the event to be happened

Answer (score 0):

These are my two preferred ways to address this. Many times I actually use both of these methods in combination for a given alert, which has helped me catch a lot of issues before alerts land in production.

---

You can write unit tests for your alerting rules and run them via `promtool`. It will let you manually specify input series (which can be whatever you want) and compare actual vs expected alerts.

Official docs:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/unit_testing_rules/

There's also an article here:
https://www.robustperception.io/unit-testing-alerts-with-prometheus

---

If you want to deploy real alerts to a few different places with some parameters changed, that's a great use case for a data templating language. There's a relatively popular way of doing that, by creating a "mixin" with the [Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/) language. This lets you write your alerts once, but parameterize them for each environment.

There are a lot of resources & examples here: https://monitoring.mixins.dev/

I imagine you could also do this same sort of thing with CUE or a normal language like Python, however Jsonnet is the most widely used in this particular case. Beware that the learning curve is pretty steep, but it's very powerful for a multitude of use-cases once you get the hang of it.